What does 'seinen Mann stellen' mean in the context of Brecht's 'Galilei'?
Towards the end of Scene 1 Galilei says:

Ich gebe es zu, es macht mir Spaß, ihr meine Herren Venezianer, in eurem berühmten Arsenal, den Werften und Artilleriezeughäusern meinen Mann zu stellen.

He seems to be saying that he enjoys playing his part in Venetian life, but I may be misreading this rather strange expression. Any offers of a good translation?

Can you provide the full quote? I found a source where the part that you left out between "Arsenal" and "meinen Mann" may be relevant, but I don't know whether it's the original.

@raketenolli There doesn't seem to be anything left out - My edition has the same complete sentence.

@tofro the quote originally left out e.g. "den Werften und Artilleriezeughäusern"

Stellen can mean (among a lot of other things) "to provide" or "make available".

Für das kommende Sommerfest stellt das Rote Kreuz Zelte, Tische und Bänke
Zur Bewachung des Munitionslagers stellt die Bundeswehr eine Kompanie

Seinen Mann stellen thus doesn't quite mean "play your part in the Venetian life" but rather it basically means "provide one's services" or "make oneself available", or simply "be useful". It is somewhat archaic and I can only find it in two places: German literature of up to the first half of the 20th century and Swiss German, where it seems to be in use until today.
The idiom has been somewhat superseded by "seinen Mann stehen" today, which more or less means the same thing.
A proper translation could be

I do admit to enjoy providing my services, my dear Venetians, in your famous arsenal, the shipyards and artillery armories

My English edition of the play translates the quoted text a bit more liberally as

I admit that it amuses me to prove my worth to you
gentlemen of Venice, in your famous arsenal and your dockyards and your cannon foundries.

Another edition translates as

I admit it amuses me to do my bit for my Venetian friends, working in your great arsenal with its shipyards and armories.

Why they jointly decided on "amuse" as the translation for "es macht mir Spaß" escapes me, however. That would definitely not have been my first choice in that context.

Agree with the answer but disagree with the meaning of "seinen Mann stehen", whose meaning is more along the lines of "to stand one's ground", "to man up" (from dict.leo.org).

@Raketenolli Agree that "seinen Mann stellen" and "seinen Mann stehen" are not exactly identical, but as close as possible. That's why "more or less".
